# Changing the centre of transformation/mapping in polar coordinate MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, transformation, coordinate

After applying the following code I get output mapped image started from **centre top point**. How can I put the starting point to left bottom corner? So, the output image should be stretched from left bottom point(not from top centre as it is now)...

```
im = imread ('peppers.png');
im = rgb2gray(im);
[nZ,nX] = size(im); 
theta = ((0:(nX-1))-nX/2)*(0.1*(pi/180)) - pi/2;
rr = (0:(nZ-1))*0.1e-3;

%% Plot image in rectangular coordinates
figure
imagesc(theta*(180/pi), rr*1e3, im)
xlabel('theta [deg]')
ylabel('r [mm]')

%% Create grids and convert polar coordinates to rectangular
[THETA,RR] = meshgrid(theta,rr);
[XX,YY] = pol2cart(THETA,RR);

%% Plot as surface, viewed from above
figure
surf(XX*1e3,YY*1e3,im,'edgecolor','none')
view(0,90)
xlabel('x [mm]')
ylabel('y [mm]')
```